# Neo4J browser - Saving diagram in database

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I want to know how can I modify the `neo4j Browser` so that along with saving Graph Data I can also save visual Node position in Database.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to accomplish? Is it that you want to explicitly specify the node positions to use in the graph visualization? Or is it that once the visualization physics simulation has stabilized you want to determine the node positions as a result of the force directed layout and save those as properties on the node?

Comment: @WilliamLyon The later one. Neo4J provides way to store data into Db via API. I want to store the positions of Node too that are rendered on Canvas so that it can be loaded back from Db